# Bug in Directory.GetParent?

Tags: .net, base-class-library

I was hit in the face by a very weird behavior of the `System.IO.Directory.GetParent` method:

```
string path1 = @"C:\foo\bar";
DirectoryInfo parent1 = Directory.GetParent(path1);
Console.WriteLine (parent1.FullName); // Prints C:\foo, as expected

// Notice the extra backslash. It should still refer to the same location, right ?
string path2 = @"C:\foo\bar\";
DirectoryInfo parent2 = Directory.GetParent(path2);
Console.WriteLine (parent2.FullName); // Prints C:\foo\bar !!!
```

I would consider it a bug, but this method has been there since 1.0, so I guess it would have been detected by now. On the other hand, if it's as designed, I can't think of a sensible explanation for such a design...

What do you think ? Is it a bug ? If not, how do you explain this behavior ?

Comment: It is important to recognize why the .NET framework has *two* classes that deal with directories.  One of them guesses, the other one verifies.  You know the difference.

Comment: @Hans: actually, neither Directory nor DirectoryInfo verifies anything... The path I used for my test doesn't actually exist on my filesystem, and both classes are perfectly happy to deal with it (as long as I don't do something that really requires the path to exist, of course). Anyway, apparently Directory guesses wrong... IMO it should treat both paths exactly the same

Comment: I ought to verify but, sigh, the odds that it is fixable are so very small.  There's just no point.  Post this to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @Hans, I agree: even if it's a bug, fixing it would be a breaking change, so they probably won't do it. I [posted to Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/614862/inconsistent-behavior-for-directory-getparent) anyway...

Comment: This behaviour is now documented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some googling reveals [some thoughts](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=406238):

> ```
> DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\parent\child");
> Console.WriteLine(di.Parent.FullName);
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\parent\child\");
> Console.WriteLine(di.Parent.FullName);
> ```
>
> Both return "C:\parent"
>
> I can only assume `Directory.GetParent(...)` can't assume that `C:\parent\child` is a directory instead of a file with no file extension. `DirectoryInfo` can, because you're constructing the object that way.

---

Personally what I think is that when there is a backslash, the string is treated as a path to the "null file" inside the directory (that is, a file with no name and extension). Apparently, those can exist (there should be a link, but for some reason I can't find anything).

Try constructing a `FileInfo` object out of `path2`. You'll see it's properly constructed, has `String.Empty` as its name and extension, does not exist and has `C:\foo\bar` as its `DirectoryName`. Given that, the situation makes sense: the parent object for this "null file" is indeed `C:\foo\bar`.

Comment: Yes, I thought of something like that, but it doesn't really make sense: the case without a final backslash works fine (the parent is be `C:\parent` whether `child` is a file or directory), it's the case *with* the final backslash that is failing: `c:\parent\child\` is obviously a directory, not a file (no file path ends with a backslash). And even if it *could* be a file, its parent should still be `c:\parent`...

Comment: Regarding the workaround with `new DirectoryInfo`: that's what I did eventually. Actually my question wasn't really about "how to solve that issue", but rather about "why does it behave like that"

Comment: +1 for your last edit. Now it makes sense, I guess... even though I wouldn't have designed it that way

Answer (score 3):

I agree with GSerg.  Just to add some additional firepower, I'm going to add the following code snippets obtained with Reflector.

The Directory.GetParent function basically just calls the Path.GetDirectoryName function:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static DirectoryInfo GetParent(string path)
{
    if (path == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    }
    if (path.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_PathEmpty"), "path");
    }
    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPathInternal(path));
    if (directoryName == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
}
```

The Parent property of the DirectoryInfo basically strips off a trailing slash and then calls Path.GetDirectoryName:

```
public DirectoryInfo Parent
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    get
    {
        string fullPath = base.FullPath;
        if ((fullPath.Length > 3) && fullPath.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
        {
            fullPath = base.FullPath.Substring(0, base.FullPath.Length - 1);
        }
        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
        if (directoryName == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName, false);
        new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, info.demandDir, false, false).Demand();
        return info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting... I didn't even think of checking with Reflector (very unlike me...). So the problem is actually with Path.GetDirectoryName, not Directory.GetParent

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty interesting. First when I read this I was pretty sure this would be a bug, but when I thought a little bit longer about it I came to the conclusion that *probably* the intent is that path should not be a directory but a full or relative path to a file. So

> c:\somenonexistingpath\to\a\directory\

gets interpreted as a path to a file with no name in ...\directory. That's kind of silly, but if we assume that the programmers at Microsoft were expecting a full path to a file, it makes sense not to cover this case.

**EDIT:**

Note that

> c:\dir\makefile -> c:\dir
>
> c:\dir\build.msbuild -> c:\dir

give the parent as expected.

Comment: That would make sense, but the documentation doesn't say anything about the path being a file or directory path... I assume they would have mentioned it if the method expected a file path. And a file with no name wouldn't make a lot of sense ;). Anyway, I think I'm going to file a bug report on Connect, just to see what MS has to say about that.

Comment: A file with no name doesn't make sense, but my argument is that they had no expectations that people would be assuming a path to a directory. I agree that the documentation should be clearer.