# ASP.NET Directory.GetParent seems to be returning the actual folder path, not the parent path

Tags: asp.net, directory-structure

I want to get the parent directory path of my solution's startup project, by testing that code

```
string parent = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Server.MapPath("~/"));
```

I get the directory where my solution's startup project is currently placed. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why this happens, at the momemt. But you can do

```
string parent = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/")).Parent.FullName;
```

to get the parent directory path.

I try to find a answer why `System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Server.MapPath("~/"))` does not work and update this if i found something.

#### Update

I found a possible answer on another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964037/bug-in-directory-getparent) who **GSerg** say

> I can only assume Directory.GetParent(...) can't assume that C:\parent\child is a directory instead of a file with no file extension. DirectoryInfo can, because you're constructing the object that way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because `Server.MapPath` is appending a `\` at the end of the path (even if you remove it from your `MapPath`), for example:

```
C:\foo\bar\
```

If you try to get the parent directory of that, it will give `C:\foo\bar` without the slash.

So this will work:

```
var path = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Server.MapPath("~").TrimEnd('\\'));
```

Here is an alternative:

```
var path = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~")).Parent.FullName;
```