# how to go one step backwards in path in C#

Tags: c#, filepath

I want to get the path that my application is located in. I get the physical path by following code:

```
string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
```

I get something like this as the result:

```
D:\\Projects\\UI\\IAC.SMS.MvcApp\\
```

I know that I can sepetare the string by "\" and combine them together. But is there an easy way to go one step back and get this?

```
D:\\Projects\\UI\\
```

Comment: How about appending ../ to the path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [Directory.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName("D:\\Projects\\UI\\IAC.SMS.MvcApp\\");
var parentName = Directory.GetParent(directoryName).FullName;
```

Or

```
var parentName = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\Projects\\UI\\IAC.SMS.MvcApp\\").Parent.FullName;
```

Comment: Note that you still need to `.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)` to get it working with path provided by OP.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No you don't need any trim. `Path` and `Directory` classes takes care of all those hairy details

Comment: `Directory.GetParent("D:\\Projects\\UI\\IAC.SMS.MvcApp\\").ToString()` :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, that doesn't work. But you shouldn't use string manipulations for path. I've updated my answer to use robust way(to work across the different platforms)

Comment: @B.K. Yes that doesn't work, but I've updated my answer to show how to avoid string manipulation.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Have you tested it?  It won't return the `UI` parent directory, as OP is requesting.

Comment: @B.K. yes I tested and that works for me. What happens in your case? I tried in [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pXuQ75) sadly no permissions. But try it locally and reply please. Are you talking about the `\\` in expected string? That's not how a directory will be represented. It should be `D:\\Projects\\UI` only.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel If the end is not trimmed, I get the directory prior to the ending directory separator.  I understand that's not how directory is represented, but that's how OP has it, so the solution must conform to the original problem, unless the OP realizes what needs to be adjusted.  It would be a good idea to inform the OP of such possibility or they'll be chasing their tail trying to fix the "bug."

Comment: @B.K. How about my alternative solution to the problem using `DirectoryInfo`? Does that works? Also refer [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964037/bug-in-directory-getparent)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, that works.  However, like I said, the OP needs to know of that possibility and why you're providing an alternate solution.  I don't need that link, but you should include it in your answer as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

Directory.GetParent will work in some cases, but it involves a performance penalty due to the creation of a DirectoryInfo object which will be populated with all sorts of information about the directory that may not be needed (e.g. creation time). I'd recommend [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) if all you need is the path, especially since with this method the path doesn't have to exist and you don't have to have permission to access it for the call to succeed.

```
var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;

var parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
```

Comment: You need `.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)`

Comment: What I mean is that it will incur the overhead of such an object being created since it is the return type of the method (edited to better state this).

Comment: @MikeNess Ah, I see what you mean.  Thanks, I didn't realize of the overhead.